# Linux Unix /proc Rename

Tags: linux, mount, proc

How can I rename `/proc` to something else forcefully?

`mv /proc /0`

gives

`mv: cannot move ‘/proc’ to ‘/0’: Device or resource busy`

Comment: proc is process information pseudo-filesystem. It is usually mounted on /proc and its read-only. Maybe you can mount it with read/write but i don't really see what is the point of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I just want to rename any directory present under / especially proc which is pseudo filesysytem!! I mentioned proc coz i wanted to explore what happens if i rename proc

Comment: Then your exploration is completed. If you rename /proc, you got an error message stating you can't do that (and shouldn't anyway). /proc is hardcoded in several commands so renaming it would break them.

Comment: I don't think you are able to rename/unmount etc /proc while the OS is running.

Comment: The whole idea of renaming `/proc` is simply going to break things. Quite a few user space utilities, like ps(1) for example, expect `/proc` to be `/proc`. What you're trying to do is like trying to take a sedan and replace its steering wheel with a football and its dashboard with a cup of coffee before asking why on earth do the readings look funny.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot rename a directory on which a filesystem is currently mounted.

(Why not? I expect it would mess up a lot of kernel data structures that keep track of mounted filesystems.)

Linux lets you change the directory that a filesystem is mounted on, however. You can do this:

```
mkdir /0
mount --move /proc /0
```

After this, the proc filesystem will be mounted on `/0`, and `/proc` won't be a mount point anymore.

Don't do this on a production system, of course. It won't completely break your system, however, it'll just make some programs work badly or not at all (for example, say goodbye to `ps`). Keep a root shell open, and run `mount --move /0 /proc` to get the proc filesystem back where applications look for it.